# opencv - how to do a template match without scale?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to match playing cards. I assumed since the cards are all unique a template match might be the right way to go.

I have the `templates`(images) in a folder, these are just the card.

Now when I try to match them with several cards and table in the picture I get 0 matches at `threshold = 0.8`.

I read up and it seems to be a problem of scale. i.e. if I understood it correctly if the card picture(template) is not on the same scale as the one where I want to detect the card then it will not get detected.

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Here is the code I am using.

```
mport pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import pyscreenshot as grabimage
import os


img_de = cv2.imread('/media/xxx/cards/match2.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_de,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

os.chdir('/media/xxx/cards/template-for-matching/')
templates = os.listdir()
# templates = ['9s.jpg']
for template in templates:
    print('checking: ' + str(template))
    t = cv2.imread(template,0)
    w,h = t.shape[::-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,t,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_de, pt, (pt[0]+w, pt[1]+h),(0,255,255),1)

    cv2.imshow('detected',img_de)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    input('Wait')
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

EDIT:

The accepted answer does the job.

I have gone with a different approach as my use case is specific and I can change the scale of where I am getting the `template` images and the `test image`

I am using the following command to make sure the scale remains the same. (Ubuntu, terminal command)

```
# Install wmctrl
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
# Command to resize the window
wmctrl -r string -e 0,left,up,width,height
```

This is from an answer: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94859/resizing-windows-to-a-particular-width-and-height-instantly)

Comment: Perhaps you can post some example images. Typically template matching only works for shifts and not when images are different in scale or rotation. If the latter, then you mostly need to process at every scale and rotation. If you have orientation, perspective and scale changes, then  you might consider feature matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a pyramid of your reference image, see [this official opencv tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d1f/tutorial_pyramids.html). Then you add an outer loop to your code that loops over all image sizes. In this pyramid you take the template with the strongest match and threshold this match.

See the code taken from [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/):

```
# loop over the images to find the template in
for imagePath in glob.glob(args["images"] + "/*.jpg"):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and initialize the
    # bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None

    # loop over the scales of the image
    for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
        # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
        # of the ratio of the resizing
        resized = imutils.resize(gray, width = int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
        r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

        # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
        # from the loop
        if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
            break
        # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
        # matching to find the template in the image
        edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        # check to see if the iteration should be visualized
        if args.get("visualize", False):
            # draw a bounding box around the detected region
            clone = np.dstack([edged, edged, edged])
            cv2.rectangle(clone, (maxLoc[0], maxLoc[1]),
                (maxLoc[0] + tW, maxLoc[1] + tH), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.imshow("Visualize", clone)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

        # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then update
        # the bookkeeping variable
        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
            found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

    # unpack the bookkeeping variable and compute the (x, y) coordinates
    # of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
    (_, maxLoc, r) = found
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r))

    # draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I cannot leave comment on his answer, it seems because I'm a new user. This method does a decent job, the calculated correlation will be weaker when not exact same size but still you get a higher score than the background noise floor. I'd implemented this in the past, and know from experience.

Comment: Then please show code and example images for a proper answer. If you do not have privileges to post images, you can post to some free hosting service and put the URLs here.

Comment: @fmw42 does that look ok?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thanks.

Comment: @neatnib Thanks for the answer, may I know how to check the accuracy %age? I changed the result  = cv2.TM_CCOEFF to cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED and added `threshold = 0.97
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)` which gives an empty array but the code still gives a match. How to maintain a certain level of confidence in the match?